# How to identify the grid cells with the specific values in a large raster data in R?

Tags: r, bigdata, raster, memory-limit

I am trying to identify the grid cells with the specific values (e.g., the values > 10, or the values between 30-50) in a large raster date (with 28,384,082,320 cells in my case). I cannot do it using the transitional ways because of the memory limit. Any easy way to do that? Thanks so much.

Comment: You might have a look at the [CRAN Task View: High-Performance and Parallel Computing with R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html), section "Large memory and out-of-memory data".

Comment: Large raster are handled by [terra](https://rspatial.org/terra/pkg/1-introduction.html) via reading chunks from raster on disk.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the R package terra, but didn't find the solution.